# Postgres Primary Key as varchar is not working

Tags: postgresql

First of all can I give Varchar for primary key? Here is my create table;

```
CREATE TABLE appinfo (
  app_id VARCHAR (30) PRIMARY KEY,
  app_secret VARCHAR ( 500 ) NOT NULL,
  app_name VARCHAR ( 255 ) NOT NULL,
  app_type VARCHAR ( 255 )  NOT NULL,
  prog_lang VARCHAR ( 255 )  NULL,
  description VARCHAR ( 255 )  NULL,
  created_on TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW()
);
```

And I am trying to insert below value

```
INSERT INTO appinfo (app_id, app_secret, app_name, app_type)
  VALUES ('ABC1', 'aaaaaaabbbbbbccccccccc', 'AccountInfoAPI', 'API');
```

but this shows below error;

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type integer: "ABC1"
LINE 2:  VALUES ('ABC1', 'aaaaaaabbbbbbccccccccc', 'AccountInfoAPI...
```

I am very new to Postgres and I am not sure where is this Integer coming from. Or is that because Primary key is always Integer in Postgres?

Comment: You obviously created `app_id` as `integer`, **not** as a varchar as you claim to have done. If `app_id` really is declared as `varchar`, your insert _will_ work: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=5b9274195696b66e9dc1c8e0a60d91af

Comment: Are you sure you connected to the same database and/or schema for the create table and the subsequent query.  As indicated Postgres has *no problems with varchar primary keys*.